# How to use a variable to change image?

Tags: android

`imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_1);`

There are 3 images img_1, img_2 and img_3

Is it possible to use the variable xyz as the image name? Like instead of img_1,how do I use img_xyz

Answer (score 0):

YMMV but you create 3 int variables. To each you assign a value like so:

```
int img_abc = R.drawable.img_1;
int img_def = R.drawable.img_2;
int img_xyz = R.drawable.img_3;
```

Then assign to your ImageView like this:

```
imageView1.setImageResource(img_abc);
imageView1.setImageResource(img_def);
imageView1.setImageResource(img_xyz);
```